# Firefox addons after update [Loki Beta]

Tags: release-loki, firefox

I'm using the Loki Beta (Installed from Beta 1 and only updated apps). Today I've installed a few new updates to elementary OS and elementary Apps, after these updates I opened Firefox and I've found multiple new addons installed that are not removable. Could someone explain, if this is normal, why did this happen, should I remove these addons, if so, how?

(GreseMonkey, HTTPS-Everywhere, LightBeam, Reddit Enhancement Suite and ublock origin were installed by me)
[image: Addons]

Answer (score 1):

These are the extensions that have been installed system-wide. So you can only disable them in Firefox.

You can however remove these packages (`xul-ext-lightbeam`, `xul-ext-kwallet5`, etc.) from your system, but note that this affects all users of the computer.

You can get the list of the extensions

```
$ apt cache ^xul-ext
```

You can remove them (for exemple the lightbeam one)

```
$ sudo apt remove xul-ext-lightbeam
```